# Typescript / Angular drill down property checking

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a simple generic way in Typescript/Angular to see if a complete path to a property exists and has a value?

For example
Could I have a function like

```
if (thisExists(aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd)) {
 ...
}
```

Where thisExists would determine somehow that it needs to check

```
if (aaa == null) return false
if (aaa.bbb == null) return false
```

etc
I know from the html perspective there's a ?. operator, but is there something on the typescript side?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, which is called `optional chaining`

```
if (aaa?.bbb?.ccc?.ddd) {
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny, this seems to be correct.  I just have to figure out why vscode is flagging it as an error.

Comment: @landers are you using resharper? Because it sadly has no support for the latest typescript versions.